# How insert new font and force the change in UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton

I try change the size and font of button, but the changes don't work!

I try using Interface Build, and after delete and test again with this code:

```
[botaoCadastrar.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:18]];
```

But don't work!

I followed this tutorial:

The solution for that is to add your fonts to your app, so you will have a unique app design. To do so, simply follow these steps:

> 1 - Add your font files to your project in XCode  (The files should
>   appear as well in “Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources”).
>
> 2 - In your “Info.plist” file, add the key “Fonts provided by
>   application” with type “Array”.
>
> 3 - For each font you want to add to your project, create an item for
>   the array you have created with the full name of the file including
>   its extension (e.g. myfont.ttf).
>
> 4 - Save your “Info.plist” file.

Comment: MyriadPro isn't a standard iOS font, did you add the font to your project? http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set UIButton title label font size programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465305/set-uibutton-title-label-font-size-programmatically)

Comment: Yes i try insert this font in my project, I will complement the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **MyriadPro** font to your project and to **info.plist** file for key **UIAppFonts** (Fonts provided by application). Then you can use your code to set font,

```
[botaoCadastrar.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:18]];
```

**Reason:**

The MyriadPro font is not iOS default font. You can find default font list here,

1. iOS 6 - http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht5484
2. iOS 7 - http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht5878

Comment: I insert the font name wrong, thx!! The correctly is @"Myriad Pron"; I don't inset whitespace between the names.!

Answer (score 3):

Set the font of the button's.

```
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:14.0];
```

If you want a custom font, please refer this link.

http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];
```

this is working if not check font name or button outlet is properly attached

Comment: I will complement the question because it comes from a source that does not have the Xcode. I am trying to insert this source into the project.

Comment: then you check your font first apply this font on simple UIlabel if there this font working then you check UIbutton outlet

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *botaoCadastrar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[botaoCadastrar setAttributedTitle:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:18]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[botaoCadastrar setAttributedTitle:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:10]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```