# How can i set wC hR font size programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

[image]

I am using Constrain for ipad and iphone.. 
so now i want to change button font size (wC hR) prograamatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465305/set-uibutton-title-uilabel-font-size-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
let wSize = self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
let hSize = self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass

if wSize == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact && hSize == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular {
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: FontNameCode, size: size)
}
```

Comment: I am using Objective C. Can u please provide me code on it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that tag in your post. I really don't know Obj-C well enough to convert it. But you're just creating two `UIUserInterfaceSizeClass` objects, then checking to see if they are the right size.

Answer (score 1):

Set Font Size as below.

**Step 1:** Set fonts as System for size classes

[image]

**Step 2:**  Subclass UILabel and override "layoutSubviews" method like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  // Implement font logic depending on screen size
  self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize];
}
```

May be it will help you.