# Changing text size of uibutton doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've created a button in story board and I'm trying to set **font size** and **font style** programmatically as follows:

```
_login.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_login.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[_login.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.f]];
[_login setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

But the button **text size** remains the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: First verify for IBOutlet part. Your button should not be nil when try to change its property.

Comment: Someone gave you a -1 so I gave you a +1, because I don't think this is a -1 question. You have already got a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Swift 3.1***

```
_loginButton.titleLabel?.font = _loginButton.titleLabel?.font.withSize(yourSize)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[_login.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]
```

**Option A**:

```
[_login.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f*Ratio]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**objective c:** both will work perfectly

(first)

```
[_loginButton.titleLabel setFont: [_loginButton.titleLabel.font fontWithSize: size]];
```

(second)

```
_loginButton.titleLabel.font =[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.f];
```

**swift:** if anybody want in swift

```
_loginButton.titleLabel?.font = _loginButton.titleLabel?.font.fontWithSize(sizeYouWant)
```

for more datails you can verify:
[Set UIButton title UILabel font size programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465305/set-uibutton-title-uilabel-font-size-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

*TRy this code:*

```
[_login.titleLabel setFont:[_login.titleLabel.font fontWithSize: yourSize]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Use yourButton.titleLabel.font

```
_login.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
```